# py2exe error: raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname

Tags: python, py2exe

I have a python program MyPictures.py with following imports

```
import os 
import gtk 
from os.path import isfile, join 
import shutil
import Image
```

I wrote following setup,py

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
#import os
import sys

__import__('gtk')
m = sys.modules['gtk']
gtk_base_path = m.__path__[0]

setup(
    name = 'MyPictures',
    description = 'Some handy tool',
    version = '1.0',

    windows = [
                  {
                      'script': 'MyPictures.py',
                  }
              ],

    options = {
                  'py2exe': {
                      'packages':'encodings',
                      'includes': 'cairo, pango, pangocairo, atk, gobject,',
                  }
              },
)
```

I ran

> python.exe setup.py install

Output is

running install running build running install_egg_info Removing
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MyPictures-1.0-py2.7.egg-info Writing
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MyPictures-1.0-py2.7.egg-info

Then I ran

***python.exe setup.py install***

```
running install
running build
running install_egg_info
Removing c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MyPictures-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
Writing c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MyPictures-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
```

And then I ran

***python.exe setup.py py2exe***

```
running py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 37, in <module>
    'includes': 'cairo, pango, pangocairo, atk, gobject,',
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run self._run()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 296, in _run 
    self.find_needed_modules(mf, required_files, required_modules)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1297, in find_needed_modules mf.import_hook(mod)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 204, in find_head_package         raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname
ImportError: No module named
```

How can I fix this error? This is first time I am using py2exe, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`packages` and `includes` should be a `list` type. Replace the `options` section with this:

```
    options = {
                  'py2exe': {
                      'packages':['encodings'],
                      'includes': ['cairo', 'pango', 'pangocairo', 'atk', 'gobject'],
                  }
              },
```

Comment: thanks micromoses, you rock. It works without any issue.

Comment: The exe worked without a flaw in win8.1 where it is generated. I then copied the dist folder to another win7 computer(installed with MS Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Pkg pub 29-11-2007, no python installed). When I executed the exe I see following error, I do not know what I am missing `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyPictures.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "gtk\__init__.pyc", line 40, in <module>
  File "gtk\_gtk.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "gtk\_gtk.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.​`

Comment: I know some stuff about distutils, but not so much about windows. I would try to build the package on the same platform as target system (win7), but am not sure. Anyway, you should probably post a new question for this in SO.

Comment: Thanks micromoses, I solved it by using `pyinstaller`, instead of using `py2exe`. Thanks again.